# No wiki Markdown references while answering a question?

Tags: support, edits, markdown

How come there are no Markdown references when answering a question?  When asking a new question there is a short Markdown reference with a link, when answering a question there is nothing.  If I need to reference Markdown I have to scramble around to get it.  This is something I have noticed on all sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The editor has a little question mark button which will open the Markdown reference.

Comment: Not sure why I missed that?